# MySql Doing two counts with two different wheres from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

**Table 1**

```
"id"    "name"      "description"   "path"                              "country"   "status"
"1"     "Title 1"   "Description 1" "US > Consumer > Home Applicances"  "US"        "0"
"2"     "Title 2"   "Description 2" "US > Business > Legal Charges"     "UK"        "0"
```

I'm trying to do two `counts` with different `wheres` from the same table.

I came across other questions here, but none like the way I'm doing it.

I'm currently doing it with two sqls and a lot more code:

```
select count(id) from table where id = 1 and select count(id) from table where id = 2
```

If both were there, I'll go on with the rest of my script. How can I do something like this in MySql?

Comment: @Prix . . . Why did you delete your solution?  I think it is better than the one chosen.

Comment: @GordonLinoff well I've made it as a comment because my solution would read all entries rather then specific selected ones as the WHERE would provide and on huge tables it may become a burden to use.

Comment: @Prix . . . That is making big assumptions that may not be true.  First, you are assuming that there is an index on `id` (which is clearly *not* a primary key or a `count()` wouldn't be needed).  Second, you are assuming that the selectivity of the selections is quite low.  If there is no index or if the selectivity is high, then the chosen solution essentially requires two scans of the data (and less efficient scans without an index).  Finally, you can fix your query just by adding `where id in (1, 2)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff indeed and I completely forgot I could still place the `where` on it. But I still have doubts about which would perform better for this.

Comment: @Prix . . . With the `where` clause, yours should perform better, both when `id` is index and when it is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use subselects.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_one FROM table WHERE id = 1) a,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_two FROM table WHERE id = 2) b
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you -

```
    $query = "SELECT SUM(Case when id=1 then 1 else 0 end) as count_one,
SUM(Case when id=2 then 1 else 0 end) as count_two FROM table";
```